# Android: UI not refreshed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a very weird bug that buzzed me for a few days now..

I have an activity that displays a fragment on the whole screen inside a FrameLayout.
The fragment can change (let's say, I click a button, it displays the new fragment on top of the first one by calling add & addToBackStack).
Inside the main fragment, there is a recycler view that loads some clickable elements, some of which starts a new fragment and some others updates the UI of the current fragment

Until months, it worked perfectly fine, but recently it does not (I probably did some change but can't find the root cause).

The symptoms are the following:

- I clicked one button that is supposed to be toggled (switching from enable to disable state for example). Right now, the onClickListener is triggered, but the UI is not rendered even when calling notifyDataSetChanged! If I manually scroll, the UI is updated. If I call recyclerView.scroll(0,0), the UI is updated too.
  In that case, I tried to debug: when notifyDataSetChanged is called, nothing happens. Like litterally nothing, the views are not even bind or anything (I'm not building a new list of element, I'm calling it from main thread, ...)
- I clicked one button that is supposed to open a new fragment on top of this one. Right now, the onClickListener is triggered, but the new fragment is not displayed. However, if I scroll, the fragment is suddenly displayed. If I don't scroll and click other buttons that are supposed to open fragments too, nothing is rendered but when I'll scroll, the UI will suddenly be updated and the stack of fragments will be rendered correctly.

The code used to load fragments is the following:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment(), tag)
                .addToBackStack(tag)
                .commit();
```

All clickable elements are inside a RecyclerView of the first fragment to be loaded.

Comment: could you make a video ?

Comment: try `.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment(), tag)` instead of `.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment(), tag)` and it does not affect your backstack

Comment: When switching to replace, nothing is displayed: first fragment is displayed, but not the other ones and back navigation displays empty page too. However, always thought replace was incompatible with backstack, so there might be something to investigate here, thanks!